# Why are the newly taken photos on my Nikon D5600 replacing older photos?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, memory-card, nikon-d5600

I bought a D5600 in 2017 and recently the newly taken photos keep replacing the older photos. This issue led to the loss of a third of the photos taken… I tried to find these lost photos in the memory card folder but failed to do so.

Does anyone know if this is an issue with the camera or the memory card?

Also, the battery is consumed super-f st (a fully charged battery lasts for less than one hour of shooting), in case this info is relevant.

Answer (score 5):

A possibility is that the image counter has rolled over and the camera is re-using the old numbers (though normally camera start a new directory when this happens), or somehow due to battery fault the camera has restarted it numbering.

Or the card is faking its real capacity (frequent in no-name cards, and knock-offs), and now that you have written all the real parts, it erases old stuff to make space for your new images.

In any case you cannot trust a SD card for long term storage, especially if is often written to. You should export your pictures to some device for archival (typically to PC first, for culling, and then archive/backup), and empty the card before reusing it.

And yes, batteries wear out (especially if you let them discharge due to infrequent use). Batteries and SD cards are consumables. For SD cards you should stick to brand names (Sandisk, Kingston...) from established vendors (Amazon itself is OK, Amazon marketplace, much less so), for batteries there are excellent aftermarket ones what are less expensive than the camera company ones.

Comment: Amazon comingles their memory cards with the ones provided by marketplace vendors. They do this in the name of efficiency. You never know any more what you're going to get with memory cards, batteries, lens filters, etc. from amazon. You can order directly from amazon and still receive a fake that was introduced into amazon's system by a third party marketplace vendor. If the warehouse with the 3rd party vendor's product is closer than the warehouse with amazon's own product, they'll send the vendor's and then give the vendor ownership of the one in their other warehouse.

Comment: Thank you so much. Based on my recent usage experience, I think that image counter has rolled over and the camera is using the old numbers is the most likely issue. Are there any solution you would suggest? Should I fix on my current camera or should I buy a new one? Thank you! :)

Comment: As said in most answers, it is not normal practice to keep your old pictures in the camera or even on an SD card. The number rollover is usually around 10K shots... so these must be fairly old shot... What are you going to do if you change the camera, or it get stolen/lost, or the SD card dies of old age (and they do...)? This said this kind of camera normally starts a new directory/folder when is restarts the counter. I can't be more specific because I use Canon cameras.

Answer (score 3):

Photos should never disappear on their own. If your older photos are disappearing from your SD card, its filesystem may contain errors. FAT32 – which is widely supported – is very prone to errors if you are disconnecting the card from any device without first ensuring it's not in use (power off the camera, safe disconnect in smartphone or PC). What is less likely is that your SD card is failing.

Before doing anything, you should copy all photos from the card. You might then try recovering images using any software like Piriform Recuva before doing anything further.

You can then check both problems using a desktop computer with any OS; in Windows you need to check for errors with both checkboxes checked:

[image: Screenshot of MS Windows error checking utility]

The OS will then report if any errors were found.

Comment: Running filesystem check with automatic errors fix (per image) will not help much and can mess the additionally the things.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have no idea how you came to that judgement.

Comment: Because this "fix" will overwrite information on the card and may lead to additional lost of information. Much wise is to create image of the SD and do all these tests on the image.

Comment: @RomeoNinov It cannot lead to additional loss if you actually read my whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Battery - this is consumable and as this is 6 year old battery it's normal it can't keep charge. Just buy new battery.
2. SD card - this is also consumable. The usual workflow is: you make some photos, return home and transfer the photos on the computer, then format the card (in camera). So the probability you will succeed to recover old photos is quite small, just next time do not use SD card for long time storage.